# Use of the definite article with the word "time" in context

Tags: definite-article

Tell me please if I need to use *the* before *time* in the following senteces.

> As (**the**) time goes by people are getting smarter.
>
> Ancient people learnt how to make better tools as (**the**) time went by.

I have definitely heard a native english speaker use *the* before *time* in similar context when talking about the past, but what about the present?

Comment: I think I have already answered this question from you in the past: abstract words don't generally take the: happiness, time, unhappiness, Time in your sentence is both an abstract idea and an  uncountable noun. Tempus fugit=in Latin, that means Time Flies. However, with a genitive, it would take the: The time of day is easy to read on that watch face. The time **of** day.

Comment: Lambie: I am aware that with abstract nouns articles are not generally used, but I have heard a native enlish speake use "the" with "time" in the context similar to that I have given, and that confused me.

Comment: You have heard something like: The time of day I like best is X; that time of life is difficult, We had the time of our lives; The time I went to London [which is countable]. Time as given on a clock or as the passage of time does not take "the". In your sentences, **the** is wrong. There is a famous British comedy called: As Time Goes By

Comment: Lambie: I have definitely heard "as the time went by", and that has confused me. Now I guess the speaker made a mistake saying that.

Comment: Lambie: Here is the video: https://youtu.be/wGBDShN8F-E. It is at 7 minut 54 second

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Before I saw your last comment, I was just about to say that I could imagine someone using "as the time went by" in a situation like: "Around 1500, the situation was such-and-such, but already in 1800, the situation was completely different. So, as the time went by, people learned to blah-blah-blah."  The speaker would refer to a span of time that they are keeping in the back of their mind (in this example, 3 centuries).

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Re your video, I haven't watched all of it to see if the speaker is possibly referring to a span of time between some event (or a series of events)– an event X, e. g., a point in time when certain tribes traveled to places where food was unfamiliar — and the present time; or a point in time when most people didn't possess a certain trait — and a point in time when this trait became widespread, but I think this is implied. Whatever that event is, the speaker has a certain period in the back of his mind, and this finds expression in his using "the" here. This is highly situational.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Your example sentences lack context, so they are simply general, abstract observations. In the absence of context, there would be no reason to use "the".

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope But please note that this is just how _this_ particular speaker _chooses_ to frame _his_ narrative. It does **not** mean that if there is a span of time to be detected anywhere in the context, one _should_ use "the". Nope. This is this speaker's private choice of framing his narrative as a description of a certain arc of development of events. In fact, this "the" might be the only indication that this speaker thinks this way. The choice of "the" expresses something very specific. You shouldn't take it as a guidance for your usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Time" with the definite article would signify a specific time, as in,

> Do you remember the time when we were so poor we had to eat ramen?

or Michael Jackson's famous song:

> Do you remember the time
>
> When we fell in love
>
> Do you remember the time
>
> When we first met, girl

Even if "the time" is not followed by "when.....", it will normally be specified elsewhere in the text, or the speaker will *allude* to a specific time that the person s/he is speaking to would remember.

> Those were the times!

is a phrase that would be used when someone is being nostalgic, after mentioning which time(s) exactly that was/were (college years, or else).

Another option:

> I could have baked three cakes in **the time** it took you to bake just one!

Here again, "the time" is defined as that specific stretch of time in which this person baked a cake.

Your examples just refer to the general passage of time, not to specific stretches of it. So no article is necessary.

Comment: That's right. Time is an abstract noun there.